# IOT Edge Hub: testing for offline storage

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We use Azure IOT and `edgeHub` and `edgeAgent` as modules for Edge runtime. We want to verify the capability of *Offline storage* is configured correctly in our environment

We have custom `simulator` module connected to custom `publisher` module that publishes to an API in the Cloud. The `simulator` is continuously producing a message around 10KB every 2 seconds.  The `publisher` module could not talk outside because of a blocking firewall rule. I want to verify all the memory/RAM allocated for `edgeHub` is used and later overflows to `disk` and uses reasonable available disk space.

This exercise is taking longer to complete even when I run multiple modules/instances of `simulator`.

Queries:

1. How can I control the size of memory allocated to `edgeHub`. What is the correct `createOptions` to control/reduce allocated memory. It is currently allocated around 1.8GB.
2. I see generally during the exercise, RAM keeps increasing. But at some point, it drops down a little and keeps increasing after. Is there some kind of GC or optimization happening inside `edgeHub`?

   ```
   b0fb729d25c8        edgeHub                 1.36%               547.8MiB / 1.885GiB   28.38%              451MB / 40.1MB      410MB / 2.92GB      221
   ```
3. How can ensure that any of the messages produced by `simulator` are not lost. Is there a way to count the number of messages in edgeHub?
4. I have done the proper configuration to mount a directory from VM to container for persistent storage. Is there a specific folder inside `edgeHub` folder under which messages would be stored when overflown?

Comment: I think this file gives good insights on how storage works in edgeHub module: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/storage/MessageStore.cs

Comment: Also see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities

Comment: @sergaz-msft thanks for replying. i have seen the offline-capabilities page before. i observer1.88GB allocated for edgeHub when there is only 2GB available on VM. I believe the system swaps before even edgeHub overflows to disk. Do you know how to control memory allocated for a container? I want to verify messages overflow in our setup.

Comment: Hi Rag, I believe that most of your questions in this thread were answered [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688682/iotedge-how-to-requeue-message-that-could-not-be-processed). Can you rephrase the question and\or post the answer to your questions so others can learn? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will document the answers after the input I have received from Azure IoTHub/IoTEdge maintainers.

- To control memory limit of containers/modules on Edge, specify as below with appropriate max memory limit in bytes

```
"createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\": { \"Memory\": 536870912 }}"
```

- Messages are persistent because the implementation is RocksDB which stores to disk by default
- To make the messages persistent even after `edgeHub` container recreation, mount a directory from Host to Container. In the example below `/data` from Host is mounted to appropriate location within `edgeHub`

```
            "env": {
                "storageFolder": {
                    "value": "/data"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the memory usage the metrics feature will be generally available in the 1.0.10

[Monitor IoT Edge Devices At-scale](https://labs.iotedge.dev/codelabs/monitor-iotedge/)