# iotedge: How to requeue message that could not be processed

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

There are `publisher` and `consumer` custom modules that are running on an Edge IoT device. The `publisher` module keeps producing messages at constant rate no matter `consumer` module processes it or not. The `consumer` module POSTs the message to external service and given that there is no Internet connection, the `consumer` module would like to requeue the messsage so that is not lost and tried again.

I do not prefer to write an infinite loop to keep retrying; also if the module is restarted the message would be lost. So i prefer to requeue the message to edgeHub/RocksDB.

Where do I find documentation on available responses that can be provided for IoTHubMessageDispositionResult? what is the response to be sent if message needs to be requeued?

```
if message.processed():
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.ACCEPTED
else:
    return IoTHubMessageDispositionResult.??
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement your own requeuing of messages.  IotEdge provides offline functionality as described in this [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extended-offline-operation-with-azure-iot-edge/) and on this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities).

The edgeHub will locally store messages on the edgeDevice if there is no connection to the IotHub.  It will automatically start sending those messages (in the correct order) once the connection is established again.

You can configure how long edgeHub will buffer messages like this:

```
"$edgeHub": {
    "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "routes": {},
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
            "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
    }
}
```

The 7200 seconds (2 hours) is also the default if you don't configure anything.

By default, the messages will be written to a folder within the edgeHub docker container.  If you want to store them somewhere else you can do so with this configuration:

```
"edgeHub": {
    "type": "docker",
    "settings": {
        "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
        "createOptions": {
            "HostConfig": {
                "Binds": ["<HostStoragePath>:<ModuleStoragePath>"],
                "PortBindings": {
                    "8883/tcp": [{"HostPort":"8883"}],
                    "443/tcp": [{"HostPort":"443"}],
                    "5671/tcp": [{"HostPort":"5671"}]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "storageFolder": {
            "value": "<ModuleStoragePath>"
        }
    },
    "status": "running",
    "restartPolicy": "always"
}
```

Replace **HostStoragePath** and **ModuleStoragePath** with the wanted values. Example:

```
"createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "Binds": [
                    "/etc/iotedge/storage/:/iotedge/storage/"
                  ],
                  ...
                }
              }
            },
            "env": {
              "storageFolder": {
                "value": "/iotedge/storage/"
              },
              ...
```

Please note that you probably have to manually give the iotEdge user (or all users) access to that folder (using chmod).

**Update**:

If you are just looking for the available values of **IoTHubMessageDispositionResult** you will find the answer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/device/iothub_client_python/iothub_client_python.py):

```
class IoTHubMessageDispositionResult(Enum):
    ACCEPTED = 0
    REJECTED = 1
    ABANDONED = 2
```

**Update 2:**

Messages that have been **ACCEPTED** are removed from the message queue because they have been successfully delivered.

Messages that are **ABANDONED** are added to the message queue again and the module will try to send it again as defined in the retryPolicy.  For more insight on the retryPolicy you can read this [thread](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/832).

Messages that are **REJECTED** are not added to the message queue again.

Comment: i am not asking about sending messages to IoTHub. i am asking about inter-module communication. The consuming module wants to requeue for some reason as it could not process the message successfully at a given point in time.

Comment: what is the behaviour of edgeHub on receiving ACCEPTED or REJECTED or ABANDONED from a consumer module? or what should be sent so that message is requeued?

Comment: Okày thanks. What is retry policy and where is it documented ?

Comment: Did you read my Update 2? Did you follow the link i provided there and did you read zu that thread? If that leaves any questions about retryPolicy so some research before asking further questions.